# Google Sheets Script - If or statement. Restrict onEdit to specific sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Super quick question. I have this function I want to run on entire workbook, except two specific sheets.

This is my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() != "Total" || sheet.getName() != "DataRange" ) { 
    someAction();
  }
}
```

This just does not work, the code runs on all sheets no matter what. This is probably a noob question but.

Comment: You know that you can post an answer to your own question, right?

Answer (score 0):

not an "answer" as you already answered your own question, but an alternative:
I'll prefer to use an indexOf I found that (in this case) clearer thant the switch:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (["Total","DataRange"].indexOf(sheet.getName()) == -1 ) { 
    someAction();
  }
}
```

I just identify in an array all the sheet that I want to avoid and then check that the current sheet is not one of then (return -1)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using switch instead

```
switch (sheet.getName())  {
        case "Total":
            
            return;
        case "DataRange":
            
            return;
        default:
            doSomething();
            break;
    }
```

---

Answer by [Kenny Bones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73715/kenny-bones) moved from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39270640/3) to answer space.